# Why does this recursive method for a sudoku-solver keep on spinning?

Tags: java, recursion

In a school assignment we're supposed to make a soduko-solver. I have a recursive method that's supposed to help me solve the soduko-puzzles. It goes like this:

```
public void setNumber() {

if (getNext() == null) {

    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    if (acceptValue(i)) {
        value = i;
    }
    }
    board.stopRec();
    return; 

} else { 


    if(predefined()) { // if the square allready has a number
    getNext().setNumber();
    } else { // find value for undefined square

    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        if (acceptValue(i)) {
        value = i // Does the Row class take notice of this?
        getNext().setNumber();
        }
    }
    /* no value was assigned */
    value = -1;

    }

}

}
```

The Board class has a method initGrid, that creates all the Squares and link them together using a nextSquare reference

```
class Board {

[...]

public void initGrid(int nSquaresBoxRowCol, int nRowsBox, int nColsBox, int[][] values) {

[...]

/* Create the rows, columns and squares */
Square prev = null;
for (int row = 1; row <= nRowsBoard; row++) {

    //Row r = new Row(row, squares[row-1]);
    Row r = new Row(row);
    rows[row-1] = r;

    for (int col = 1; col <= nColsBoard; col++) {
    if (row == 1) {
        Column c = new Column(col);
    }

    Square current = new Square(row, col, Math.ceil((float)row / (float)nRowsBox), Math.ceil((float)col / (float)nColsBox), values[row-1][col-1], r, this);

    if (!((row-1) == 0 && (col-1) == 0)) {
        prev.nextSquare = current;
    }

    prev = current;
    squares[row-1][col-1] = current;

    r.addSquare(current);

    /* Fill the boxes with squares */
    boxes[(int)(Math.ceil((float)row / (float)nRowsBox)) - 1][(int)(Math.ceil((float)col / (float)nColsBox)) - 1].addSquare(squares[row-1][col-1]);
    nSquares++;

    }

} // END for (int row ...
```

Objects of the Row class hopefully hold the square objects added to them in the initGrid-method in the Board class.

```
class Row {
int id;

Square[] squares;
ArrayList<Square> squareList;

Row(int id) {
this.id = id; // not currently used for anything
squareList = new ArrayList<Square>();
}

boolean checkValue(int val) {
System.out.println("Checking values for row " + id);    
Iterator<Square> iter  = squareList.iterator();
while(iter.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println("Value (boolean checkValue() in Row): " + iter.next().value);
    if (iter.next().value == val) {
    System.out.println("returned false");
    return false;
    }
}
return true;

}

public void addSquare(Square s) {
squareList.add(s);
System.out.println("class Row, method addSquare: Square with value " + s.value + " added to row.");
}
```

}

---

About the semi-recursive method

The method is inside class Square, all the squares are assembled in a two-dimensional array. The method is suppose to call itself for every square on the sudoku board. All the squares have a Square nextSquare pointer pointing at the next square in squares[][]. getNext() returns nextSquare.

acceptValue(i) checks the Squares' Row to see if there's a Square-object there with the value of i, it returns true if there isn't (Row has a square[], with its squares, assigned to it from Board)

I really thought this would do the trick, but the recurrsion just keep on spinning.

The only thing I can think of is that maybe the squares in the Row-object don't get the value-update going on in the recursion, and that this might cause the recursive method to go on forever. But I still don't see why that would make any sense, it should just give me wrong values according to the sudoku rules.

Please advise if I should include any more code.

Any suggestions is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: From first look I'd say your `getNext()` method is never returning `null`, but we'll need more code to help. Why aren't you running this in a debugger?

Comment: I'm not familiar with running debuggers. What code should I include, and can you elaborate on the how to run code in a debugger?

Comment: This doesn't look recursive to me. Yes, you're calling `setNumber()`, but you're calling it for _another square_. I can't figure out what that `for` loop is trying to do, or what it means when `getNext()` returns `null`. You describe a lot of your code with words; is it guaranteed to be right (as in, it comes from the teacher) or could it be sending wrong signals to the code you posted?

Comment: I had a sop("NULL") in the if (getNext() == null) block, and I could clearly see it scrolling up the cmd-window.

Comment: If you are using an IDE, The debugger button is usually next to the Run button. If you are not using an IDE, IMHO, you are just making life hard for yourself.

Comment: Maybe I just don't understand sudoku, but why do you have all those calculations for rows and cols in the code you added in your edit? Isn't it always a 9x9 grid?

Comment: One possibility is that you're not getting into an infinite loop at all.  For a difficult(or impossible) puzzle to solve, your algorithm is going to run in O(2^n) time(Where n=the number of cells).  With 81 squares, that could take quite some time.  Even with a solvable, non-trivial puzzle it could take a while.

Answer (score 0):

Well for one thing, if all of your other code works as expected and `acceptValue(i)` will really choose correctly everytime, then you would want a return after your `getNext().setNumber();`

Something like

```
for(i=1;i<10;i++){
    if(acceptValue(i)){
        value = i;
        getNext().setNumber();
        return;
    }
}
```

Otherwise if your code chose 2 as the value when the `setNumber()` returns it will try 3, 4, 5... and so on.

Comment: I tried this, now I got rid of the infinite looping, but the solution was wrong.

Comment: @Aksel Mathias, I had a feeling it would be, it seems you need to go over your logic on how you derive a correct answer. The first number that fits isn't always going to work for the row, column, and square that your box is in. A recursive method is more suited for a brute force approach to solving Sudoku in which case you would pick a number that fits and then try the next box and try to find another number that fits if there isn't one then you return back and try the next available number for the previous box.